# Running runipy from launchd

Tags: python, macos, launchd, jupyter-notebook

I’m attempting to periodically run a jupyter notebook by utilizing runipy and osx’s launchd.

This works from the command line

```
/path/to/interpreter/python.3.4 /path/to/runipy/main.py /path/to/notebook/nb.ipynb
```

but a similar approach in a launchd plist fails to launch the notebook

```
<key>ProgramArguments</key>
<array>
    <string/path/to/interpreter/python.3.4</string>
    <string/path/to/runipy/main.py</string>
    <string/path/to/notebook/nb.ipynb</string>
</array>
```

When I check the console log i just see this cryptic error

```
Service exited with abnormal code: 1
```

Any ideas on why this is failing?

Note: I’m currently using launchd to run py files on this machine using a similar approach.

UPDATE:

I added the following lines to my plist per wij's suggestion

```
<key>StandardErrorPath</key>
<string>/tmp/com.your.thing.err</string>
<key>StandardOutPath</key>
<string>/tmp/com.your.thing.out</string>
```

and got

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 3940: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got around the "ascii" error by creating an intermediary py file that uses runipy and opens the notebook with encoding="utf-8"

nb_launcher.py

```
from runipy.notebook_runner import NotebookRunner
from IPython.nbformat.current import read

notebook = read(open("nb.ipynb", encoding="utf-8"), 4)
r = NotebookRunner(notebook)
r.run_notebook()
```

and calling that from launchd

```
<key>ProgramArguments</key>
<array>
    <string/path/to/interpreter/python.3.4</string>
    <string/path/to/py_file/nb_launcher.py</string>
</array>
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you using LaunchControl? I'd recommend using it so you can easily capture Standard Error in the console and see what's underlying abnormal code 1. Without LaunchControl, you can also add these keys to the .plist:

```
<key>StandardErrorPath</key>
<string>/tmp/com.your.thing.err</string>
<key>StandardOutPath</key>
<string>/tmp/com.your.thing.out</string>
```

Comment: Thanks, i'll check it out